# CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://localhost:8545

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, json-rpc, geth-debugging

I have started geth using below:

```
geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain * --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi personal,web3,eth,net
```

and this is my web3.js code:

```
<script src="/bower_components/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function send() {
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
        }
        if(!web3.isConnected()) {
            console.log('not-connected');
        } else {
           console.log('connected');
        }
    }
</script>
```

first console.log said `"not-connected"` and got an error: `Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://localhost:8545.`

Comment: check if the port is open using netstat cmd

Comment: yes it is opened. tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8545          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1521/geth

Comment: try 127.0.0.1 instead localhost

Comment: did but same error

Comment: install metamask and check if it connect to your nodein localhost mode

Comment: Put single quotes around * `geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi personal,web3,eth,net`I try your code and it gave me a cross domain error with the '*' everything works fine, I get the connected message

Answer (score 0):

Just a small error of scopes. Your web3 variable goes out of scope as soon as it is declared.

```
<script src="/bower_components/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var web3;
    function send() {
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
        }
        if(!web3.isConnected()) {
            console.log('not-connected');
        } else {
           console.log('connected');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Note that I have declared `var web3` explicitly outside the function

Comment: not working. can u plz tell how can i connect remote url ? eg: web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://110.249.35.167:8545"));

Comment: const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://110.249.35.167:8545'));